# InitialValue does not set in RequiredFieldValidator DDL

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

For some reason the dropdownlist's initial value doesnt get set. It always loads some random value instead. When I look into the markup I can see all the list items including the one with -1 value. I also tried clearing browser cache and explicitly setting the SelectedIndex/Value in code to 0/"-1", but cant seem to figure out what is going on. Any idea?

Here is how I am doing it:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server" CssClass="select_Box" OnPreRender="LoadGenders">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <div class="error"> 
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator                                     
                                    ID="RequiredFieldValidatorGender"
                                    Runat="server"
                                    Enabled="true"
                                    InitialValue="-1"
                                    ControlToValidate="ddlGender"
                                    SetFocusOnError="true"                                        
                                    Display="Dynamic">Gender Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<select name="pagecolumns_0$pagecontent_1$contentleftcol_0$ctl00$ddlGender" id="pagecolumns_0_pagecontent_1_contentleftcol_0_ctl00_ddlGender" class="select_Box">
<option value="-1">--Select Gender--</option>
<option selected="selected" value="M">Male</option>
<option value="F">Female</option></select>
```

as you can see, it is randomly selecting Male. Alsow, I notice that, last time I fill the form I set it to Male before hitting submit. May be is it caching the selection?

Here is the .cs:

```
protected void LoadGenders(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack) return;
            ((DropDownList)sender).Items.AddRange(Constants.GenderWithSelect);
        }
public static ListItem[] GenderWithSelect = (new[] { new ListItem("--Select Gender--", "-1") }).Concat(Gender).ToArray();
 public static ListItem[] Gender = new[]
                                              {
                                                  (new ListItem("Male","M")),
                                                  (new ListItem("Female","F"))
                                              };
```

Comment: What you mean by ddl's initial value doesn't set? can we see the generate markup of ddl.

Comment: please, post the .cs part , how do you bind the drop down list?

Comment: I've modified my question to include .cs and html markup.

Comment: So it is initially set to "-1" when you first load the page correct? It is after you set it to Male and click submit it is maintaining the value. That should be a normal asp.net DDL behavior. I don't see now where does the RFValidator come into your issue?

Comment: @gbs sorry.. I dint say it right. I know the normal behavior. So, this is whats happening: 1. solution builds and I load the page, I see -1 is selected. I say cool. 2. I select Male and submit the form. 3. I come back to the form, I see Male is selected. not cool. 5. I clear cache, switch browser and load the page again. and still Male is selected. Its weird. Its always Male until I make some change and build the solution again.

Comment: Yes, it is weird. Is that all the code you have for the ddl? See if you can create a separate test page with that code and replicate the issue. If you can, please post that page so we can test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it has something to do with load sequence of the controls. So, adding selectedindex to LoadGenders did the trick.

```
protected void LoadGenders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack) return;
        ((DropDownList)sender).Items.AddRange(Constants.GenderWithSelect);
        ((DropDownList) sender).SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and it appears that the generated html didn't have the correct field bound to the "value" of the select options.

What you must get must have this format :

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlGender" id="MainContent_ddlGender" class="select_Box">
  <option selected="selected" value="-1">not set</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

In order to have this, I had to set the DataValueField of the DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server" CssClass="select_Box" OnPreRender="ddlGender_PreRender" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text">
```

(Just replace the DataTextField and DataValueField with the name of the properties of your class)

Comment: These values don't get populated from a database. So, I am not sure how to consume DataValueField. I've added more info to the question.